# Show 2D array (grayscale image) in heatmap in python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I'm a beginner in working with images in python and I'm trying to display 2D array, 500px x 500px, array((500, 500)), which I usually display as an grayscale image as a color image, in heatmap. [image: I would like this:]

to be displayed like this:
[image]

I tried but I couldn't find the answers in the internet, and what I found didn't work for me. Please help.

I don't really have much code, I only know that this one:

```
my_img = plt.imread(filename)
plt.imshow(my_img, cmap="hot")
```

doesn't work, it displays the same image, in grayscale.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html  and  https://code.google.com/p/visvis/wiki/example_colormaps

Comment: What do you mean when you say it *"doesn't work"*? Please be more specific. Do you get an error? Does the output differ from what you want? How so?

Comment: What is the shape of `my_img`? If the image is a 3 dimensional array, where the last dimension has a size of 3 or 4, it is interpreted as an array of RGB(A) values rather than a grayscale image, and therefore your choice of colormap will have no effect.

Comment: it is a 2d array. the value of an element signifies intensity

Comment: Can you display a random array in color, e.g. `plt.imshow(np.random.randn(5, 5), cmap='hot')`?

Comment: Does `my_img = np.random.random((500,500))`,
`plt.imshow(my_img, cmap="hot")` come out in orange-black for you? (Does for me.) If not, check what your `my_img` is after being read back in.

Comment: it does for me also. But:    `my_img = plt.imread(filename)`, `plt.imshow(my_img, cmap="hot")` still shows it in grayscale.

Comment: Could you print the contents of part of your `my_img` array (e.g. `my_img[:10, :10]`)? What is the `dtype`? What range of values does it contain?

Comment: dittoing ali_m. If something that's *definitely* a 2D array of floats works, and your read-in image doesn't.... check the read-in image. (Maybe you're getting a (500,500,3) array with all three RGB values the same.)

Answer (score 0):

try giving [pcolor](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html) a try.  It's the more usual analogy to a "heatmap".  `imshow` is more aligned with the display of images true to the color values in the array.  The fact that your ideal image is inverted from your practice image also tells me pcolor might be a better choice.